# React Native Rendering Components Alternatively by using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to render the list alternatively into two columns in a grid. I intend to do so using a flag variable in my component state and change its value each time I return a `CardDetail`.

I commented out the `this.changeState()` statements because they don't seem to work as intended.

Please help me figure this is out, I am new to React/React Native.
Thanks in advance.

```
renderAlbums() {
    return this.state.albums.map(album =>{
      this.rend2(album)
    }
    );
  }
rend2(album){
if(this.state.flag === 0)
{
  //this.changeState();
  return (<CardDetail key={album.title} album={album}  />);
}
else
{
 //this.changeState;
return (<View />);
} 
}

changeState(){
  if(this.state.flag === 0)
{
this.setState({flag:1});
}
else
{
  this.setState({flag:0})
}
}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);

    return (

      <ScrollView>
      <Grid>
      <Col>{this.renderAlbums()}</Col>
        <Col>{this.renderAlbums()}</Col>

      </Grid>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are triggering `changeState` with and without parenthesis. Maybe this is the issue? Also, calling `changeState` on every render will case an infinite loop in your code.

Comment: I was calling `changeState` without parenthesis.  Changed it. But still does not work. The simulator goes blank. So to fix the infinite loop issue what should I change?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. You have two lists and whenever `CardDetail` is rendered you need to change state somehow?

Comment: I have only one list, I want to render the components alternatively(rendering the first, skipping the second, and so on) into two columns. I intend to do so by changing value of flag and using it as shown in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to change the state in this case. Just pass a parameter to your `renderAlbums()` method and use it to pick every other album in your list:

```
renderAlbums(col) {
  return this.state.albums.map( (album, index) => {
    if (index % 2 == col)
      return (<CardDetail key={album.title} album={album}  />);
    else
      return (<View/>);
  } );
}
```

Then in your `render()` method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Grid>
        <Col>{this.renderAlbums(0)}</Col>
        <Col>{this.renderAlbums(1)}</Col>
      </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

This code has not been tested, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change your approach a little bit and render both columns at the same time. So then you can switch between which column you want to render `CardDetail`.

```
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <Grid>
      {this.state.albums.map((album, index) => 
        <View key={index}>
          <Col>{index % 2 === 0
            ? <CardDetail key={album.title} album={album}  />
            : <View />
          }</Col>

          <Col>{index % 2 !== 0
            ? <CardDetail key={album.title} album={album}  />
            : <View />
          }</Col>
        </View>
      }
    </Grid>
  </ScrollView>
```